# how do I start and stop a timer from an options page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Right now i have this 1 minute timer in my background page  that runs forever i would like to be able to start and stop it from an options page.

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[0, 0, 0, 255]});

var i = 1;
window.setInterval(function(timer) {
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:String(i)});
i++;
}, 60000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval()` method of the Window object schedules a function to be invoked repeatedly at intervals of the specified number of milliseconds. `setInterval()` returns an opaque value that can be passed to `clearInterval()` to cancel any future invocations of the scheduled function. Read more about [How Javascript Timers work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/). With that you can write something like this:

```
My.Controller = {};

(function() {  
      var interval = 10;
      var timer = null;

  function init (param) {
    // initialisations if any   
  }

  // Override the default interval of 10 seconds by passing new interval 
  function startAction (param, tInterval) {
    // Set a timer
    var ti = (!tInterval) ? interval : tInterval;
    timer = setInterval(My.Controller.action, ti * 2000);    
  }

  function action () {
    // Logic here
  }

  function stopAction () { clearInterval(timer); }

  var c = My.Controller;
  c.init = init;
  c.startAction = startAction;
  c.stopAction = stopAction;
})(); // end Controller
```

Now you can say `My.Controller.startAction()` to start the timer and and `My.Controller.stopAction()` to stop.

Read and explore about [namespaces in JavaScript](http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/26/basic-javascript-part-8-namespaces/).
Hope this helps.